# How to identify dependency chain using Go Modules

Tags: go, go-modules

How can I identify the import path of a module that exists in `go.sum` but not in `go.mod`? I'd like to know which module in `go.mod` is importing the module listed in `go.sum`, and the entire chain between them.

I'm in the process of removing a deprecated module, `logrus`, from one of my modules and my own dependencies and want to ensure none of my own code still uses it, and which other code does use it.

The Go module has both a `go.mod` and a `go.sum` file. In the `go.sum` file, a module `github.com/sirupsen/logrus` appears that does not appear in the `go.mod` file.

When I recreate the `go.sum` file by deleting `go.sum` and running `go test -v ./...`, the `go.sum` file is recreated with `logrus`.

There is no direct or indirect mention in `go.mod`, such as:

```
github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.6.0 // indirect
```

`go mod why` returns the following:

```
$ go mod why github.com/sirupsen/logrus
# github.com/sirupsen/logrus
(main module does not need package github.com/sirupsen/logrus)
```

`go mod why -m` returns the following:

```
$ go mod why -m github.com/sirupsen/logrus
# github.com/sirupsen/logrus
(main module does not need module github.com/sirupsen/logrus)
```

How can I find out what module in `go.mod` is importing a module, `logrus`, which is listed in `go.sum` but not `go.mod`?

Here's the module:

- Module: https://github.com/grokify/goauth
- [`go.mod`](https://github.com/grokify/goauth/blob/72b088f655853f0984d5933a699cef41812656df/go.mod)
- [`go.sum`](https://github.com/grokify/goauth/blob/72b088f655853f0984d5933a699cef41812656df/go.sum)

Comment: Try running  with the -m switch: `go mod why -m github.com/sirupsen/logrus`

Comment: That returned `(main module does not need module github.com/sirupsen/logrus)` which I've also added to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```sh
go mod why github.com/sirupsen/logrus
# or 
go mod graph | grep logrus
```

Comment: This returns `(main module does not need package github.com/sirupsen/logrus)`.  I've added this to the question for the module. Does this need to be explicitly run against each module?

Comment: This is indirect dep, but you still can find what is using it. pelse see update.

Comment: `go mod graph | grep logrus` worked. Thanks!

Comment: indirect deps not always shown, only if go.mod missing for imported module, its deps will be in `go.mod`.

Comment: Very good info! I had noted `// indirect` deps in `go.mod` but that wasn't listed either. I've added this to the question to make it more useful. I was able to learn which modules use the module and it isn't my own code.